# Will SVM classifier be a good choice?

Tags: classification

I have a script that scans text files and searches for keywords related to cryptography. And I'm scanning source code files. A lot of the times, I get back some evidence of cryptography like "AES_encrypt", but sometimes it can be a false positive, e.g. the keyword "crypt" in the string "cryptic words".

To get rid of false positives, I designed an app that allows a human expert to go in and flag each hit as positive or false-positive. I want to gather this data and train a supervised classifier that learns from the human's expertise and gives a probability that a certain future hit is a positive. My training data looks something like this:

```
keyword | keyword_group | is_source_file | P/FP
"aes_encrypt" | "aes" | True | P
"aes_encrypt" | "aes" | True | P
"aes_encrypt" | "aes" | False | P
"aes_encrypt" | "aes" | True | P
"aes_encrypt" | "aes" | True | FP
"aes_encrypt" | "aes" | False | FP
"decrypt_aes" | "aes" | True | P
"decrypt_aes" | "aes" | True | P
"decrypt_aes" | "aes" | True | P
"decrypt_aes" | "aes" | True | FP
"decrypt_aes" | "aes" | False | P
"decrypt_aes" | "aes" | False | FP
"decrypt_aes" | "aes" | False | FP
"rsa_key" | "rsa" | True | P
"rsa_key" | "rsa" | True | P
"rsa_key" | "rsa" | True | P
...
```

Keywords are organized in groups. For example, "aes_encrypt" and "aes_decrypt" are both under "aes" group. `is_source_file` indicates whether this hit was found in a source code file like a ".cpp" or a ".py" file as opposed to other file extensions like a ".txt".

I want to give the classifier a keyword and its group and whether it was found in a source file, and I want back a probability that it is a positive. What kind of classifier do you recommend for this job? Would SVM be a good choice?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of classifiers that can do this job for you. I'll name and summarize a few here and see whether it fits your problem.

**Logistic Regression** is a probabilistic approach where it gives informarion about the statistical significance of features but you have to account for the Logistic Regression assumptions. (as far as I can recall the assumptions are similar to that of Linear Regression. You can Google this to find out more.

**K-Nearest Neighbors** is easy to understand and to implement. What this algorithm does is to check what group the input is nearest to. You have to choose the number of *k* though since the algorithm determines which classification it gives the input by a majority vote.

**Support Vector Machine** is one that you have mentioned so I'm assuming that you know how this works. The advantage of SVM is that it is not based on outliers and it is not sensitive to overfitting. However, it does not perform well on non-linear problems and it is not the best choice for data that has a lot of features

**Kernel Support Vector Machine** in order to address the problem that SVM only works for linear problems, what Kernel SVM does is that it uses the kernel trick. The kernel trick basically maps the data to a higher dimension such that they can be linearly separable. An example of a kernel trick is using the Gaussian or Radian Basis Function for SVM.

**Naive Bayes** is a probabilistic approach. It is efficient, not based on outliers and works well on non-linear problems. However the caveat here is that it assumes that all the features have the same statistical relevance

**Decision Trees** is an approach that can be easily interpretable since it creates trees where the leaf nodes are the classes. It can work on both linear and non-linear problems but it performs better when using a large dataset as opposed to a small one. It is also easily susceptible to overfitting.

There are a lot more but these are some that you can choose from to have more details on these algorithms you can do a quick Google search about it.